# Help with long table

Tags: tables, longtable

I am dealing with a long table for my document. I am a beginner in using LaTeX, so I might be doing the things really wrong, as per my MWE.  The thing is: I would like this table (that is composed of two parts) to appear in one page, or if it is split, to have a (...cont.) or something like that in the following page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}           % fleqn: align equations left
\usepackage{geometry}                                     % Custom margins 
for single page, etc.
\usepackage{fullpage}                                     % Use the full page
\usepackage{setspace}                                     % Enables custom margins, doublespacing, etc.
\usepackage{pdflscape}                                    % Use: \begin{landscape} ... \end{landscape}
\usepackage{lmodern}                                      % Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape} % To create a table in a landscape environment
\usepackage{rotating} % To use sideways table
\usepackage{rotfloat} % Use H with a sideways table
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating} % To rotate a table
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}

% Font/text:
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}                             % Font definition and input type
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                  % Font output type 
%\usepackage{textcomp}                                     % Supports many additional symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}                                      % Math equations, etc.
\usepackage{amsthm}                                       % Math theorems, etc.
\usepackage{amsfonts}                                     % Math fonts (e.g. script fonts)
\usepackage{amssymb}                                      % Math symbols such as infinity
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Max}{Max}                          % Better looking max function
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Min}{Min}                          % Better looking min function
\usepackage{color}                                        % Enables colored text
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.66}                 % Custom color: dark blue
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,bookmarksopen]{hyperref} % Enable hyperlinks, expand menu subtree
\hypersetup{                                              % Custom hyperlink settings
    pdffitwindow=false,                                   % true: window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00},                    % Fits the default zoom of the page to 100%
    pdfnewwindow=true,                                    % Links in new window
    colorlinks=true,                                      % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=darkblue,                                   % Color of internal links
    citecolor=darkblue,                                   % Color of links to bibliography
    urlcolor=darkblue  }                                  % Color of external links
%\usepackage{kpfonts}    % for nice fonts

% Images:
\usepackage{graphicx}                                     % Allows more types of images to be included
\usepackage[position=bottom]{subfig}                      % Enables arrayed images
\usepackage[section]{placeins}                            % Forces floats to stay in section
\usepackage{float}                                        % Used with restylefloat
\restylefloat{figure}                                     % "H" forces a figure to be "exactly here"
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}             % Center captions

% Tables/arrays:
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}                           % Table format - increases table spacing
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}    % Spacing for tables increased
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}                          % Spaces arrays at 1x
\usepackage{dcolumn}                                     % Align decimals in tables (as option)
%\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}                           % Align decimals e.g. \begin{tabular}{c...}

% Miscellaneous:
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000                           % Footnotes won't break across pages
\usepackage[semicolon]{natbib}                            % Bibliography and citation formating
\usepackage{datetime}                                     % Custom date format for date field
\newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}    % Defining month year date format
%\usepackage{tikz}                                        % Timelines and other drawings
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations}                             % Formating for Tikz
%\usepackage{xr}
%\externaldocument{under_estout}

% *****************************************************************
% Estout related things
% *****************************************************************
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}% Thanks to David Carlisle

\let\estinput=\input% define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \begin{tabular*}
            {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular*}
            }
        }   

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[2.75ex]
            \end{tabular}
            }
        }

% Allow line breaks with \\ in specialcells
    \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

% *****************************************************************
% Custom subcaptions
% *****************************************************************
% Note/Source/Text after Tables
\newcommand{\figtext}[1]{
    \vspace{-1.9ex}
    \captionsetup{justification=justified,font=footnotesize}
    \caption*{\hspace{6pt}\hangindent=1.5em #1}
    }
\newcommand{\fignote}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}

\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}

% Add significance note with \starnote
\newcommand{\starnote}{\figtext{* p < 0.1, ** p < 0.05, *** p < 0.01}}
\newcommand{\errornote}{\figtext{Clustered robust standard errors in parentheses}}

% *****************************************************************
% siunitx
% *****************************************************************
\usepackage{siunitx} % centering in tables
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing       = true,
        group-digits        = false ,
        input-signs     = ,
        input-symbols       = ( ) [ ] - + *,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-post   = false
        }

% *****************************************************************
% *****************************************************************
% *****************************************************************
% DOCUMENT BEGINS HERE
% *****************************************************************
% *****************************************************************
% *****************************************************************

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering{ 
\caption{Marginal effects and OLS estimates for alternative control groups}
\label{tab10}
\begin{flushleft}
\textit{Panel A: control group from 55 to 59 years old}
\end{flushleft}

    \begin{threeparttable} 
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{S
S
S
S}}
\toprule
                                        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Attend}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Labor}}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Primary}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Secondary}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Primary}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Secondary}\\
\midrule
Treatment           &      -0.009         &       0.003         &       0.004         &       0.016         \\
                    &     (0.009)         &     (0.019)         &     (0.052)         &     (0.048)         \\
2008 year dummy     &      -0.007         &       0.025         &       0.008         &      -0.037         \\
                    &     (0.008)         &     (0.021)         &     (0.061)         &     (0.048)         \\
Treatment*year dummy&       0.012         &       0.013         &      -0.001         &      -0.055         \\
                    &     (0.009)         &     (0.027)         &     (0.069)         &     (0.066)         \\
\midrule
Treatment-on-treated&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.005}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.038}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.007}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.092}         \\
F-test              &\multicolumn{1}{c}{1.087}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{3.615}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.027}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{3.511}         \\
p-value             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.298}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.058}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.870}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.062}         \\
\midrule
Observations        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{605}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{833}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{529}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{833}         \\
\(R^{2}\)           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.044}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.067}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.424}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.375}         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{threeparttable}}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering{ 
\begin{flushleft}
\textit{Panel B: control group from 50 to 59 years old}
\end{flushleft}

    \begin{threeparttable} 
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S
S
S
S
S
S}}
\toprule
                                        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Attend}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Labor}}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Primary}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Secondary}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Primary}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Secondary}\\
\midrule
Treatment           &      -0.008         &      -0.010         &      -0.009         &      -0.003         \\
                    &     (0.008)         &     (0.016)         &     (0.045)         &     (0.043)         \\
2008 year dummy     &      -0.003         &       0.010         &      -0.094\sym{**} &      -0.041         \\
                    &     (0.004)         &     (0.012)         &     (0.044)         &     (0.035)         \\
Treatment*year dummy&       0.009         &       0.028         &       0.094         &      -0.050         \\
                    &     (0.006)         &     (0.021)         &     (0.058)         &     (0.057)         \\
\midrule
Treatment-on-treated&\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.005}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.038}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.000}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.092}         \\
F-test              &\multicolumn{1}{c}{1.161}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{4.095}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.000}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{3.463}         \\
p-value             &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.282}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.044}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.995}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.063}         \\
\midrule
Observations        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{910}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{1,336}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{803}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{1,336}         \\
\(R^{2}\)           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.033}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.053}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.393}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0.364}         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
\footnotesize
\item Clustered standard errors in parentheses

\item \textit{* p < 0.1, ** p < 0.05, *** p < 0.01}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
%   \figsource{Own elaboration based on EH2007 and EH2008}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: olbap79: I was trying to understand your problem but I can't... why you consider these tables long tables? Are there other rows that could be added? Or there are other subtables within the same table? Please specify or add an image of what you want, also a photo of some handwritten scheme is ok, thank you!

Comment: you might want to clean up your preamble you load graphicx twice, you don't need to load graphics (included by graphicx) you don't need to load amsmath (loaded by mathtools) you load array twice but don't need to load it as it is included by tabularx, you load setspace twice.....